# "as" twice, next to each other in the same sentence

Tags: as, repetition

I have written this sentence, and I am not sure if it is grammatically correct. M$ Word marks the second "as" as being wrong. Take a look:

> This ensures the ticket is inserted properly, as as much as a 1/4-inch difference can cause the feeder to jam.

Is this grammatically correct? I've tried looking online for notes on this but I've come up empty handed, probably due to the short word and (potential) obscurity of such a use.

The only change I can think to make is to add `even` in between the two `as` instances.

Comment: It’s valid, with the first “as” meaning “because” or “since”. But it should be avoided in practice anyway because doubled words *look* wrong.

Comment: Microsoft Word certainly used to have a rule flagging up all repeated words, since they're almost always an error, even though in some cases the're fine (had had, that that, etc). Basically, it wasn't too bright, and it's easier to make the user re-check.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this sentence with 'having', however it is understandable and technically correct as said in the comment. Below is an alternative that may help:

This ensures the ticket is inserted properly, as having even a 1/4-inch difference can cause the feeder to jam.

Comment: Or 'a difference of as much (little?) as 1/4 inch can cause...'